# uploading 1 million images to BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am quite new to GAE and web development in general, and I am trying to work with GAE BlobStore. I am using python can not seem to find any resources on uploading a large amount of files into BlobStore.

I have read a number of resources and examples, but non of them seem to be helpful in this particular matter.

Does anyone have any resources or experience regarding this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in my project, when moving to appengine from dedicated server.
We didn't have to move 1 million, but it was about 100000.

It took some time, but at the end was done.

It was done using pretty simple solution. Just created a file upload service, just like in the examples [on blogstore docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob).

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def get(self):
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
    self.response.write(upload_url)

  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.response.write(blob_info.key())
```

And then using upload script to upload the files from localhost.

Such a script can be written in python, or even in shell script, by combination of `find`, `curl`, and `xargs`.

For speedup using several threads and doing 32 uploads in paralel helps.

For robustness, after uploading a file, we can try to download it and compare the sizes/md5, and re-uploading if something went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

We'll depending on how you plan on using the images you could upload them to Google Storage and access them from your AppEngine app using [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). If has resumable uploads and [multithreading](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_reference_guide#multithreading) for faster uploads.

Otherwise, you need to use [create_upload_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) and do the batching yourself, in batches less than 500 files at a time due to [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8032) bug.